# How to autowire Symfony cache pools services?

Tags: symfony, autowired

In Symfony 4 and 5, we have the concept of cache pools. When we define new cache pool, a new service is generated for it using the name of the pool. The problem is that since they all share the same CacheInterface, Symfony wouldn't know which service to inject if we rely solely on the interface.

My question is how to use autowire in the above case, to autowire a specific cache pool service to another service.

(I could inject the cache pool manually but if I can then I don't want to).

Comment: Imagine that you are the autowire code.  When faced with multiple implementations of the same cache interface, what criteria would you use to automatically pick one?  If you can actually articulate the criteria then it is possible that a compiler pass might work.

Comment: Hi Cerad, yes I do know the exact one I want to use. I found this link: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html. Seem like I can use variable name to suggest, so I need to define "alias" such as App\Util\TransformerInterface $shoutyTransformer: '@App\Util\UppercaseTransformer'. I will check if I have to do that myself or if Symfony has already done that (more likely not)

Comment: Okie you know what, the aliases are actually generated automatically (which can be checked by running the command debug:autowiring). I feel like this should be mentioned somewhere in their documents though. Sometimes I feel like Symfony is moving too fast they don't have time to do proper documents and we have to dig into the code alot.

Answer (score 3):

I feel bad for answering my own question, I do hope someone else will benefit from this though:

When you define your pools, Symfony will automatically create autowiring aliases for you, so you can use something like this:

Symfony\Contracts\Cache\CacheInterface $yourPoolName and Symfony will know which pool to use. Do note that the parameter name will be the camelCase version of your pool's real name.

You can check by running the command debug:autowiring to see this list.

Comment: This is the first time I saw that you could use the argument name as part of an alias.  Not really comfortable with mapping argument names to services but it's nice to know that it can be done.  I would imagine that the new [attribute capability](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-2-controller-argument-attributes) will eventually allow something like #[CachePool=name] directly in the constructor.

Comment: @Cerad I do agree with you, I don't like it much to be honest. I think they should resolve that with attributes in the future.

Comment: Symfony has the ability to "bind" arguments names to services when working with multi implementations interfaces for example. This configuration can be done for any services in your services.yml